# Draw multiple lines on mouse click but without overlapping

Tags: c#, drawing, mouseevent, overlapping

this code is working for drawing multiple lines by mouse clicks. But the lines are overlapping or intersecting even if one line is already created.

Can anyone help me how can i draw multiple lines [the working code for drawing multiple lines are given] without overlapping each other inestead it would find another round way to avoid conflicts to other lines.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    private Point _setPointA, _setPointB;
    private static List<Point> PointList = new List<Point>();
    private Dictionary<Point, Point> PointDictionary = new Dictionary<Point, Point>();

    public Form1()
    {
        PointDictionary.Add(new Point { X = 10, Y = 10 }, new Point { X = 85, Y = 85 });

    }
    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (!PointList.Any())
            {
                _setPointA = e.Location;
                PointList.Add(_setPointA);
            }
            else
            {
                _setPointB = e.Location;
                PointList.Add(_setPointB);

                //check if not intersects

                if (_setPointA.X <= _setPointB.X)
                {
                    PointDictionary.Add(_setPointA, _setPointB);
                }
                else
                {
                    PointDictionary.Add(_setPointB, _setPointA);
                }
                Refresh();
            }
        }
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var v in PointDictionary)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(SystemPens.ControlDarkDark, v.Key, v.Value);
        }

        base.OnPaint(e);
        PointList.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are collcting only two points so far. For more lines you need to collect more, best in a `List<Point> pointlist`. To draw them use `if (pointlist.Count > 1) DrawLines<pen, pointlist.ToArray());` in the paint event! Avoiding crossing lines is another matter. You can check before adding a new line by using a two GraphicsPaths and doing a set operation on two regions derived from them.. Do you know what to do when the new line would cross one of the previous lines?

Comment: This is a classic Winforms programming problem, with lots of relevant Q&As on the site already. As the previous comment suggests, the first step is to fix dealing with multiple lines. See the marked duplicate for that. Once you have solved that problem, please try to solve the "crossing" problem yourself; if you're unable to, post a new question in which you've included a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, with a clear, concise description of what the code does and what you want it to do instead.